# Logging mysql queries under MAMP Pro (MAC)

Tags: mysql, logging, mamp

I am using MAMP Pro 2.0.5 (latest)
and copied the my-medium.cnf file and placed it into /mamp/conf/  and renamed it to my.cnf
under the [mysqld] i placed

log = /Volumes/www/public/logs/mysql-queries.log

to get the log going ( i want to log all queries)

but nothing happends. I resarted mamp and when i run queries nothing gets logged. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

MAMP PRO overwrites my.cnf. So editing the file won't help you.

You need to select File > Edit Template > MySQL my.cnf from the MAMP Pro Menu. Then edit the file in the editor that pops up. and hit save.